# post request on form with validation

Tags: javascript

i built a registration form and validated it using javaScript. but i want after a user filled the form, it should post to the server. i am confused on where to place my httpRequest function. i don't know if its after validation or inside the validation function
**This is my validation function**
function formregister(e){

```
        if (first_name.value=== "" || last_name.value=== "" || user_id.value==="" || id_type.value=== "" 
            || id_no.value=== "" || address.value===""  || !terms.checked) {

         var fPassResult = '1';

           } else{
            var fPassResult = '0';

          }

          if(fPassResult === "1") { 
            window.location = "register.html";
       }else{
         Swal.fire({
              type: 'success',
              title: 'Your Registration has been Submitted Successfully',
              text: 'Click Ok to Login',
               timer: 10000
            }
             ).then(function(){
              window.location="Login.html";
             })
        }
     e.preventDefault();
    };

**And this is my post request function**
function registerationApiCall(e){
  var data = {
               "user_id":"user_id.value",
               "user_pin": "user_pin.value",
                "first_name":"first_name.value",
                "last_name":"last_name.value",
                "address":"address.value",

             };
    fetch("jehvah/api",{
            type : 'POST',
            data : data,
            dataType : 'JSON',
            encode : true,
            success: function (response, status, xhr) {
              if (result==="OK") {
                console.log("success");
              }else{
                console.log("bad");
              }
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
              console.log("something went wrong");
            }
          });


}
```

Please kindly check my post request function, i dont know if i am doing it the right way

Comment: What i am assuming is: you are checking all the variables for some condition. You need to have " else if ladder " where you need to check all the condition and place your api call inside " else condition" in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the fetch documentation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch), `success` and `error` does not exists.

The fetch function returns a `Promise`, so you can handle results as any Promise should do:

```js
fetch("jehvah/api", {
  method: 'POST',
  body : JSON.stringify(myDataObject)
})
.then(blob => blob .json())
.then(result => console.log('Success!!))
.catch(e => console.log('Failure :('))
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi ✌    when `fPassResult === "0"`   in this case inside `else{}` call registerationApiCall()
[image]
 you tell the user it's a success  after you get OK from the server which is  Asynchronous  call
&  inside fetch response you call swal.fire

for this code to work your server when checks the database  & every thing is ok  returns a msg   like this `{"msg":"OK"}`

CODE:

`else{
registerationApiCall()
}`

function `registerationApiCall` becomes

```
fetch('jehvah/api', 
    { method: 'POST',headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, body: JSON.stringify(data)})
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((result) => {
  console.log('Success:', result);
if (result.msg="OK") {
                console.log("success");
                Swal.fire({
              type: 'success',
              title: 'Your Registration has been Submitted Successfully',
              text: 'Click Ok to Login',
               timer: 10000
            }).then(function(){window.location="Login.html";})

              }else{ console.log("usres exsists / etc");}
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log("something went wrong");
});


}
```

Also  in  the request payload you  sent a group of strings  not  the variables containing the form values

Here

```
var data = {
               "user_id":"user_id.value",
               "user_pin": "user_pin.value",
                "first_name":"first_name.value",
                "last_name":"last_name.value",
                "address":"address.value",
             };
```

Change that to

```
var data = {
               "user_id":user_id.value,
               "user_pin": user_pin.value,
                "first_name":first_name.value,
                "last_name":last_name.value,
                "address":address.value
};
```